# How to put paragraph after a figure in latex?

Tags: floats, paragraphs

I want to put a paragraph after an image but latex always put the paragraph before the image. how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Don't use a floating environment if you don't want the content to float ;)

Comment: but i need the caption of the image.

Comment: Then use `\usepackage{caption}` and `\captionof{figure}{my caption goes here}`.

Comment: The package `caption` and use `\captionof`, see the package manual for more information.

Comment: Although there are already some answers: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Related: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)